# Moving SD card from Pi 2 to Pi 3: only see a "rainbow square"

Tags: boot, pi-3, raspbian-jessie

I've updated my Wheezy distribution to Jessie and was running smoothly on my Pi 2.

Moving that SD card to my Pi 3 results in the "rainbow square" on the monitor, but no apparent booting activity of any sort. This should have worked, no?

What would cause my patched-from-Wheezy-to-Jessie version to do that? Or generally what does it mean when I see the "rainbow square" but booting does not continue? I think I had the experimental OpenGL drivers loaded... could that be the cause?

I was hoping to pick up my development tasks right where I left off; alas at the moment it looks like I'm going to have to reinstall apps, my development environment and code, and re-figure out what configurations and customization I had on the Pi 2.

(The Pi 3 in question works fine with Jessie installed directly from NOOBS 1.9.2, but just not with the upgraded-to-Jessie OS that worked fine on a Pi 2.)

**UPDATE:** I stopped trying to debug/fix this.  Just cutting over to Jessie on all my Pis: Pi2s and Pi3s.

Comment: Does it still work when you put it back in Pi 2?

Comment: Yes, still works.